# Reviewing the basics of algebraic topology for further deeper study

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I am entering a Ph.D. program in pure math this fall. Over the summer, I am hoping to review the basics of algebraic topology (fundamental group, covering space theory, etc.) and I wondered if you had a particular source you would recommend for that. I'm looking for a book that has a lot of good exercises, and serves as a thorough and intuitive explication of the topics for someone who later wants to study them more deeply.

I already own (little) Munkres, Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds, and the two little books by Milnor and Wallace, and I may use those as sources. I also own Hatcher's text, but that is a bit too advanced for this task. I wanted to choose well, because I think a good source can make all the difference.

What do you think?

Comment: I would have said Hatcher-it seems it should be about the right level for someone who's already seen the theory once. Perhaps going back and forth with your other books could make it more usable.

Comment: the books you own seem right about on target. If you want something different, I suspect the dover text by Gamelin is decent, at least it wouldn't cost you much and I personally enjoy his writing (for the complex analysis, I haven't read too much of Gamelin's topology)

Comment: I think "Fundamental Groups and Covering Spaces" 
by Elon Lages Lima, is a good introduction to this part of the theory. For a second reading, I would say Hatcher remains one of the best.

Comment: See also the discussion on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778483/text-similar-to-chapter-9-of-topology-from-james-munkres/778622#778622

Comment: Relevant to this discussion is the use of groupoids as more poowerful than groups in algebraic topology. See the discussion at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one